# http header request and header response intercept using safari extensions

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, safari-extension, intercept

i want to intercept http header request and http header response both on browser client side using javascript and safari plugins. i had created a plugin and i am able to inject my script in browser, now i need to intercept http request and response i had tried many things like(webRequest of chrome) etc.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? This could be an XY problem.

Comment: my ultimate goal is to intercept and modify all incoming and outgoing http request using safari plugins

Comment: Have you find a solution ?